# Prove linear transformation of gaussian random vectors are still gaussian random vectors

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, random-variable

Let $X$ be an $n \times 1$ random vector with a normal distribution $\mathcal N(\mu_x, \Sigma_x)$. Let $Y = AX + B$.

I know that when $A$ is non-singular, I can prove that random vector $Y$ also has a normal distribution.

But what if $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix where $m \neq n$? Is $Y$ still has a normal distribution? If so, how can I prove this?

**I know how can I calculate the covariance and mean of $Y$ given $\mu_x$ and $\Sigma_x$.**

**What I want is a proof of $Y$ being a random vector that has a normal distribution.**

For example, when both $X$ and $Y$ are scalars, I know I can prove $Y$ has a normal distribution by differentiating

$$P(Y \leqslant y)=P(X\leqslant \frac{y-B}{A}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\frac{y-B}{A}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-\frac{1}{2\Sigma_x^2}(\frac{y-B}{A}-\mu_x)^2}$$

with respect to $y$.

But I am clueless when $X$ and $Y$ are vectors of different dimensions.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332441/affine-transformation-applied-to-a-multivariate-gaussian-random-variable-what

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Affine_transformation

Comment: @ChristophHanck Thank you. I know how to do the algebra, but what I don't understand is how it is a normal distribution, I've edited my question to make it clear.

Comment: why casting the downvote?

Comment: Can't say, not mine

Comment: It's a good question, the link Christoph provided actually can't be said as a proof. Typically a rigorous and yet compact proof should resort to characteristic function.

Comment: Two steps: a scalar multiple of a normally distributed RV is a normally distributed RV and the sum of two normally distributed RVs is a normally distributed RV. From these, you can conclude that a linear combination of normally distributed RVs is normally distributed. That matrix-vector multiplication is none other than linearly combining the RVs